# How do I root Redmi Note 5 Pro

Tags: rooting

I want to know how can I root my Xiaomi Redmi Note 5 pro running on Nougat based MIUI 9.2.4
I have tried searching for it but it seems that the phone is released recently so there isn't any information available

Comment: Not the time for that yet - wait for a initial TWRP port.

Answer (score 1):

there is a way of rooting the Redmi Note 5 Pro. TWRP recovery is also available now. In the mean time custom ROMs may too be available. You just need to follow some steps which will get you easier to get root access. Then you can try audio MODs or uninstalling bloatware etc.
 Follow the guide here
https://www.gizdev.com/root-redmi-note-5-pro/